# SC.stream - How to remove current Track before starting a new one?

Tags: stream, soundcloud

Im using a playlist to feed urls to SC.stream. But I can't figure out how to remove the previous Sound when I start the next Track.
My function looks like this

```
function stream (url){
SC.stream(url, function(sound){
sound.play()
)}
}
```

I know that I am missing the line where I remove the old Sound, but I don't know how to remove it and where to place the line.
thank you very much

Comment: --push-- i hope thats ok.

Comment: stop() the sc object isn't a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this is late, but a simple solution I recently found is using .destruct() on my next and previous buttons.

```
function stream (url){
  SC.stream(url, function(sound){
    sound.play();
    $('#nextbutton, #prevbutton').click(function(){
      sound.destruct();
    });
  )};
}
stream (url);
```

Note that I used jQuery, but I think the .destruct() method should still work in pure js if you refer to your buttons correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to remove the current track, you simply stop it from playing, if it is, and load the new one.

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID'
});

var playing = false;

play = function(trackId){
  if(playing){
     // Stop the current sound
     SC.sound.stop();
  }

  // Play the new one
  SC.stream("/tracks/" + trackId, function(sound){
    // Store the sound object inside the SC object which belongs 
    // to the global scope so that it can be accessed out of the 
    // scope of this callback
    SC.sound = sound;
    SC.sound.play();
    playing = true;
  });
}
```